# What I get after I compile the c file?

Tags: c, compilation

I use `gcc` compiled the `hello.c`:

```
dele-MBP:temp ldl$ ls
a.out   hello.c
```

now, when I `cat a.out`:

```
$ cat a.out 
??????? H__PAGEZERO?__TEXT__text__TEXTP1P?__stubs__TEXT??__stub_helper__TEXT???__cstring__TEXT??__unwind_info__TEXT?H??__DATA__nl_symbol_ptr__DATA__la_symbol_ptr__DATH__LINKEDIT  ?"?   0 0h ? 8
                                 P?  
                                     /usr/lib/dyldס??;K????t22 

?*(?P
     8??/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib&`)h UH??H?? ?E??}?H?u?H?=5??1ɉE??H?? ]Ð?%?L?yAS?%i?h?????Hello
P44?4
```

there shows the messy code.

I want to know what type of the `a.out`? is it `assembly language`? if is why there have so many `???` or `%%%`?

Comment: Use `file a.out` and it will identify the file as an executable.  That means it contains machine code and control information.  It is not intended to be readable by humans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several intermediate file formats, depending on the compiler system you use. Most systems use the following steps, here shown with GCC as example:

1. Preprocessed C source (`gcc -E test.c -o test.i`), but this is before compilation, strictly speaking
2. Assembly source (`gcc -S test.c -o test.s`)
3. Object file containing machine code, not executable because calls to external functions are not resolved (`gcc -c test.c -o test.o`)
4. Executable file containing machine code (`gcc test.c -o test`)

Only the first two steps generate text files that you could read by `cat` or in a text editor. This is BTW a valuable source for insight. However, you can use `objdump` to see most informations contained in the other formats. Please read its [documentation](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/objdump.html#objdump).

Each step does also all steps before it. So (`gcc test.c -o test`) generates assembly source and object file in temporary files that are removed automatically. You can watch that process by giving GCC the option `-v`.

Use `gcc --help` to see some entry points for further investigations.

There is at lot more to say about this process but it would fill a book.